# SwiftUI: How do I save the size of a window in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

How can I save the size of a window so when the user resizes and clicks on the red close button (without actually terminating the app), the window stays in the same size it was before it was closed?

I'm using SwiftUI 2.0 for macOS Big Sur. Been searching for a lot of answers but none of them have worked for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try defining the windowShouldClose(..) method on your window controller. When it is called, save the window size to user defaults. When you open the window, check for the user defaults and if one is found for the window, set the new window to the saved size.

Comment: You don't have access to the underlying NSWindows, do you? There's lots of APIs under the "Managing Window Frames in User Defaults" section of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow

Comment: This question has some suggestions on how to preserve the window size and position. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506416