# Restoring macOS window size after close using SwiftUI WindowsGroup

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

By default, on a macOS app using SwiftUI the window size is not restored after the window is closed.

Is there a way to keep whatever size & position the user gave before closing the app. Essentially I'd like **close & open** to behave in the same way to when the user **quits & opens** the app?

[image]

Is there something that should be added here?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of those things that SwiftUI lacks to cover until now, I believe you can solve the issue with app kit, but that would not be 100% okay, because appkit would manipulate view after view get appeared through a notification of an active window, then you would see view would appear in wrong position or size for a some moment then appkit would correct it, in general not a satisfying experience for you or your app users.

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.2 / macOS 12.2. Would you show your `ContentView`? Or provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: If you create a new project in Xcode, and for ContentView() you use a TextEditor (i.e. something with a dynamic size) this issue will show. Apparently in cocoa you can use autoSaveName to get around it but not here.

Comment: @MMV - did you find a solution to this problem, other than Mark's hide window solution below?

Comment: Not really, I'm using what Mark suggested

Comment: Did you check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72676028/873072 already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find out a way to work around this case by instead of closing this window we will show/hide it.

Here is how I did in my app

```swift
@main
struct PulltodoApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let mainWindow = NSApp.windows[0]
        mainWindow?.delegate = self
    }
    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        NSApp.hide(nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Even though this is the accepted solution, I personally cannot recommend this workaround from user experience point of view. This workaround will also not restore the window state on cold start

Comment: Please also keep in mind that the app submission will get rejected because there’s no menu shown for the app after the main window is closed.

Answer (score 2):

For me, neither of the suggested approaches worked to restore the window frame over app restarts. SwiftUI would always reset it.

So, I ended up manually saving and restoring the window frame from the user defaults:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Set window delegate so we get close notifications
    NSApp.windows.first?.delegate = self
    // Restore last window frame
    if let frameDescription = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "MainWindowFrame") {
        // To prevent the window from jumping we hide it
        mainWindow.orderOut(nil)
        Task { @MainActor in
            // Setting the frame only works after a short delay
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
            mainWindow.setFrame(from: frameDescription)
            // Show the window
            mainWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }
    }
}

func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    if let mainWindow = NSApp.windows.first {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(mainWindow.frameDescriptor, forKey: "MainWindowFrame")
    }
    return true
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let mainWindow = NSApp.windows.first {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(mainWindow.frameDescriptor, forKey: "MainWindowFrame")
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, approach. What is not working out for is `mainWindow.orderOut(nil)`. For some reason, this is closing my menubar app...

Comment: I can also recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/72676028/873072

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've tried the [Mark G solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72558375/21904817) and it worked, but my App menu hides from macOS top Menu Bar.

So, I've reached out to this solution:

```swift
@main
struct TestingApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let mainWindow = NSApp.windows.first
        mainWindow?.delegate = self
    }

    func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
        let mainWindow = NSApp.windows.first
        if flag {
            mainWindow?.orderFront(nil)
        } else {
            mainWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

In this case, we need to set the main Window delegate to `NSWindowDelegate` and the default implementation for `windowShouldClose` is `true`.
When you close the app and select the App icon from dock, it doesn't open.
So you need to implement `applicationShouldHandleReopen` method.

Here's a solution demo where you can see the app is restored with the same position and size:

[Link to the Demo using the default Xcode project Hello World](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByCgp.gif)